# How to sort by texture?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Now and then the phrase ["sort by texture"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22sort%20by%20texture%22) appears in OpenGL-related posts. While I see how this sort could be implemented for a single texture bound to a certain texture unit, I am not certain how this might be done for multiple textures bound to arbitrary texture units. Perhaps by capturing the state of the TUs into an integer id, then use the id as an index into either an array or a map? How to best do the "sort by texture" in an OpenGL application?

Comment: Setting aside *how* to do it, a good graphics driver should be able to do a lot of that for you, delaying drawcalls until it can rearrange them to maximize performance. Bindless textures also pretty much eliminate this problem. Considering that in a game big enough to make a difference, each model usually has its own texture set anyway. Regarding multiple units, if you can narrow down one "main" texture and some auxiliaries (like environment map) you can sort by attributes in order of frequency of change (if that makes sense).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yeah, but in an `opengl-es` environment, drivers are often lacking, have bugs even (in my experience). I don't think they optimize a great deal.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Well, in case of blending enabled and far to near rendering required the driver can not rearrange much; but then things have to be drawn in a certain order anyway. Sorting by textures is still a good practice through. The most common method is treating texture units as levels in a tree and sort in a depth-first manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating texture units as levels in a tree and do a sorted depth-first traversal is a good starting point.

Ideally what you want to do is minimize the number of texture unit state changes which may mean that the same texture gets selected and deselected multiple times in the optimal case. You suggestion of sorting the tuples of texture IDs is a good idea as well.

Comment: @user1095108: Trees are a very common data structure in graphics applications (`std::map` is not really a tree though). The usual application for trees in graphics is spatial subdivision used to quickly eliminate whole branches if they're not visible, but also to sort the scene if you need a particular drawing order (like back to front for blended shapes). However you can easily extend a spatial subdivision tree (like Kd or Octree) into non-spatial dimensions, like the textures used. But like Bartek already mentioned, today the OpenGL driver will do some internal processing as well.

Comment: If possible, would you give a simple (visual) example of such a tree? Some ASCII art.